Transaction atomic with pymongo in flask
I want to implement transaction atomic with pymongo in flask for both create and update flow.
I've implemented the transaction_atomic:
class TransactionAtomic:
__log = ApplicationLoggerFactory().get_logger("TransactionAtomic")

def __init__(self, transaction_propagation=TransactionPropagation.REQUIRED,
             sql_provider=SqlAlchemySessionServiceProvider,
             mongo_provider=MongoSessionServiceProvider):
    self.__transaction_propagation = transaction_propagation
    self.__sql_provider = sql_provider
    self.__mongo_provider = mongo_provider

def __call__(self, func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        container = Container.get_object_graph()
        self.__sql_session_service_provider = container.provide(self.__sql_provider)
        self.__mongo_session_service_provider = container.provide(self.__mongo_provider)

        request_id = None
        if self.__transaction_propagation == TransactionPropagation.REQUIRES_NEW:
            request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

        request_id_new = SessionProvider().get_request_id()
        print(f"new request id {request_id_new}")
        sql_session = self.__sql_session_service_provider.session(request_id_new)
        mongo_session = self.__mongo_session_service_provider.session(request_id_new)
        self.__log.info(f"Started transaction with request_id: {request_id_new}, mongo_session: {mongo_session}")

        def callback_wrapper(mongo_session: ClientSession):
            try:
                self.__log.info(f"Transaction started: {mongo_session}")
                ret = func(*args, mongo_session=mongo_session, **kwargs)
                sql_session.commit()
                self.__log.info(f"Committing MongoDB transaction: {mongo_session}")
                return ret
            except Exception as e:
                self.__log.error(str(traceback.format_exc()), extra={'request_id': request_id_new})
                sql_session.rollback()
                raise e
        try:
            result = mongo_session.with_transaction(callback_wrapper)
            return result
        except PyMongoError as e:
            self.__log.error(f"MongoDB transaction error: {e}")
            raise e
        finally:
            sql_session.close()
            self.__sql_session_service_provider.remove_connection(request_id_new)
            self.__mongo_session_service_provider.remove_connection(request_id_new)

    return wrapper

I've written this wrapper function to achieve this but I'm unable to achieve atomicity since the data is not getting rolled back even if I'm getting any exception at some point in the code:
with switch_collection(Order, collection(Brand, order_data['namespace'])) as NSOrder:
order = NSOrder(**order_data)
order.save(session=mongo_session)

Please help me here
